# Loop with if statement and copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, copy-paste

I am trying to copy paste from a master sheet into a max of three sheets that's why I have three values.

This code does what it should with column "C".

My sheet goes till "BO" and it will grow longer.
I could copy paste my code and change all "C" to "D" and so on but I can't imagine how long the code will be at the end.

I want to try a loop. I didn't find a good explanation on how I loop something like this.

```vb
Sub autocopyrechts()

Dim score As String
Dim score1 As String
Dim score2 As String
score2 = Range("C7").Value
score1 = Range("C6").Value
score = Range("C5").Value

If score = ("MP") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle7.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score = ("M") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score = ("MI") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle6.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score = ("Z") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle8.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score = ("PK") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle9.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score = ("G") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle10.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

End If

If score1 = ("MP") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle7.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score1 = ("M") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score1 = ("MI") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle6.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score1 = ("Z") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle8.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score1 = ("PK") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle9.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score1 = ("G") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle10.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

End If

If score2 = ("MP") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle7.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score2 = ("M") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score2 = ("MI") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle6.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score2 = ("Z") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle8.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score2 = ("PK") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle9.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

ElseIf score2 = ("G") Then
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Tabelle10.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Range, you can use Cell in your code and have a rowCounter keeping track of what row you are working with.

```
Dim score As String
Dim rowCounter as Integer

for rowCounter = 5 to 7
    score = Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value
    Tabelle1.Range("C1:C354").Copy
    Select Case score
        case "MP": Tabelle7.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        case "M" : Tabelle5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        case "MI" : Tabelle6.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        case "Z" : Tabelle8.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        case "PK" : Tabelle9.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        case "G" : Tabelle10.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
    End Select
Next
```

Hope this works for you and concept is clear

Comment: Ah ok that makes it better thank you so much, but can i do the same with the copy so it copys the same rows so if it checks D5:D7 it copies D1:D354 to the right sheet ? The final plan is that i just let the code go trough all of the master sheet an done (hopefully) i kinda know now how ich do that with the check but not the copy.

Comment: You had everywhere C so I assumed C is what you wanted. In that case, you can use: Tabelle1.Range(Cells(1,rowCounter - 2), Cells(354, rowCounter -2)).Copy It will now follow the cells C, D, E etc

Comment: Yea wording was bad sorry but yea need this to go till "BO" and more later on.
Ok maybe i am stupid but know it ignores the if or now the case statment and starts with E.
Tho i dont want steal your time to much you already helped me so much.

Comment: I am a bit lost on what you are asking for now. Do you want the case statement taken out or do you want a more dynamic approach of the source values?

Comment: To make it clear because my wording is bad i am so sorry for this, the copy action just starts From E the case statment still starts from C Thats the issue now. If it cheks the case on C it should also copie C and so on. Also it just after it finds one case it stops tho it needs to copy for each case so if there are 3 cases that matches it should do 3 copies to the 3 sheets, i dont know if i am right but i can to a For Each statment before the case for that i think not sure tho.

Comment: Sorry for adding yet antoher comment i kinda made the loop work so it loops trough with the code i got from you.
    score = Cells(rowCounter, i).Value
    Tabelle1.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(354, i)).Copy
now my only problem is that after it finds one working case it copys that without looking for the rest

Comment: Ok thats my last comment, i found the problem it was a Problem with my sheet i fixed it and know it works.
I wanna thank you for your help and time it was a big help help for a beginner like me thx to you my code is smaller and i got a idea how to loop and it works.

Comment: Sam, great you are enthusiastic and got things working. Glad I could help.